# Docker build uses chaces with --no-cache

Tags: linux, bash, docker

Since this morning I'm having issue with my builds.
I have prepared Docker file like this.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-CU10-ubuntu-20.04 AS database

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=StackOverflowExamplePassword
ARG WORK_DIR=/usr/work

USER root
COPY /certs /certs
RUN cp /certs/*.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0 

COPY /docker/database/init_db.sh ${WORK_DIR}/init_db.sh
COPY /docker/database/entrypoint.sh ${WORK_DIR}/entrypoint.sh
COPY /databases /databases

USER root
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y libunwind8 libicu66 unzip dotnet-sdk-6.0 
ADD /docker/database/sqlpackage-linux-x64-en-US-15.0.5084.2.zip ${WORK_DIR}/sqlpackage.zip
RUN mkdir ${WORK_DIR}/sqlpackage
RUN unzip ${WORK_DIR}/sqlpackage.zip -d ${WORK_DIR}/sqlpackage
RUN chmod +x ${WORK_DIR}/sqlpackage/sqlpackage
RUN ln -s ${WORK_DIR}/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x ${WORK_DIR}/init_db.sh
RUN chmod +x ${WORK_DIR}/entrypoint.sh
USER mssql

COPY /docker/database/db_init.sql ${WORK_DIR}/db_init.sql
COPY /databases/custom_hierarhies_db/Scripts/Security.sql ${WORK_DIR}/security_patch.sql
COPY /databases/custom_hierarhies_db/Scripts/HierarchyWithNodes.TestData.sql ${WORK_DIR}/init_manage_nodes.sql
COPY /databases/custom_hierarhies_db/Scripts/InitETLParams.PostDeployment.sql ${WORK_DIR}/init_params.sql
COPY /databases/custom_hierarhies_db/Scripts/FillDictionaries.PostDeployment.sql ${WORK_DIR}/data_init.sql
COPY /databases/custom_hierarhies_db/Scripts/SourceSelectionSetsView.TestData.sql ${WORK_DIR}/data_init2.sql
COPY /databases/custom_hierarhies_db/PostDeployScripts/ ${WORK_DIR}/PostDeployScripts

WORKDIR ${WORK_DIR}

EXPOSE 1433

# Execute command to expose database to container
CMD ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

problem is that every time I try to build it using `docker build -t database-local --no-cache .`  I see output.

```
...
=> CACHED [ 2/27] COPY /certs /certs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/27] RUN cp /certs/*.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/27] RUN update-ca-certificates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/27] RUN apt update                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/27] RUN apt install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/27] COPY /docker/database/init_db.sh /usr/work/init_db.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/27] COPY /docker/database/entrypoint.sh /usr/work/entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/27] COPY /databases /databases                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [10/27] RUN apt update                              
...
```

This keep happening no mater what I do. I can `docker builder prune -a`, `docker system prune -a` and everything else. Even when `docker system df` shows 0B everywhere it keep using cache...

Comment: For testing purposes, remove progressively all the COPY/RUN in order to identify what caused cache usage.

Comment: I want to find out why he still use cache, and from where.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, by reducing your Dockerfile to a minimum, you will find out what caused cache usage.

Comment: Trying to copy non-exiting path to container trigger this error. For example `COPY /databases/custom_hierarhies_db/PostDeployScripts/ ${WORK_DIR}/PostDeployScripts`

But still my problem is how it use "CACHE" when my `docker system df` looks like this 
`TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE`
`Images          0         0         0B        0B`
`Containers      0         0         0B        0B`
`Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B`
`Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B`